# Insert image to screen at touch co-ordinates

Tags: java, android, touch

I am making an app which requires an image to be placed on the screen at the location the user clicks.  The user must be able to insert multiple images on the screen at once.

So far I have set up the image that will be inserted onto the screen as a drawable

```
@drawable/texture
```

I have also put in a `touch listener` in my `activity` that should get the **co-ordinates**.  I have added this method to the `android:onClick` on my Layout.

```
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
          float x = event.getX() ;
          float y = event.getY();

      }

  }
```

This is my first question on stackoverflow so if I have forgotten any information you need please just ask.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want help with? Is it on how to place an image on the layout based on Touch? Additional info on what min sdk you want to support is required as it would determine the approach that needs to be followed?

Comment: Yea pretty much that is what I am after.  Min SDK is currently set to 2.2 but I am just using it locally on my phone.  I can change it to what ever is needed really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
      int x = (int) event.getX() ;
      int y = (int) event.getY();
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp =new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);; //Assuming you use a RelativeLayout
      ImageView iv=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
      lp.setMargins(x,y,0,0);
      iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
      iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(/*id of your image*/));
      ((ViewGroup)v).addView(iv);
  }
```

Comment: Have tried this solution but is bringing up an error on the line "v.addView(iv);"  getting this error v.addView(iv); The method addView(ImageView) is undefined for the type View

Have tried to cast it which works.  But the application crashes when  I click on the screen.

Comment: Also, make sure that the Layout you override onTouch for is RelativeLayout, filling the entire screen

Comment: It is a RelativeLayout however I made the layout in XML rather than in the Java code.  Will this make a difference?  

Here is the error code I got
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onTouch(View) in the activity class example.co.uk.example.touchapp.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.RelativeLayout

Comment: I am assuming this is because onClick methods can only contain the View as a paramater.  Any way around this?

Comment: onClick!! you should setonTouchListener not onClick

Comment: onClickListener is an interface that implements onClick while onTouchListener is an interface that implements onTouch